# Chrome Extension: How to insert CSS conditioned on variable from Chrome storage using insert CSS?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm somewhat new to Chrome Extensions, so I think I may just be missing something small, but I'm trying to allow users to load an additional page of CSS and a page of JS depending on their options (it's basically a different theme).

I'm storing the variable that should trigger the load as `tm`

Right now, in the JS page, I have:

```
var Theme;
function getVars() {
  chrome.storage.sync.get({
    tm: "",
  }, function(items) {
    Theme = items.tm;
    changeTheme();
  });
}
```

Which triggers the `changeTheme` function, and—depending on the value of `Theme`—runs the correct JS functions.

The trouble is that I also need a CSS sheet to load, but I can't figure this part out. Right now, in that same JS file, in the `changeTheme` function, I'm also calling:

```
chrome.tabs.insertCSS({file: "starWars.css"});
```

This gives me the error:

```
 Error in response to storage.get: TypeError: Cannot read property 'insertCSS' of undefined
at changeTheme (chrome-extension://ipicalmjapbogbfpaddglpachiijdffn/starWars.js:96:14)
at Object.callback (chrome-extension://ipicalmjapbogbfpaddglpachiijdffn/starWars.js:7:5)
at getVars (chrome-extension://ipicalmjapbogbfpaddglpachiijdffn/starWars.js:3:23)
at chrome-extension://ipicalmjapbogbfpaddglpachiijdffn/starWars.js:10:1
```

My manifest version is `2`, unlike the other StackOverflow posts I've found on this. You can't use background in a version 2 manifest, and I need to stay in this version for other reasons. I do have `"tabs"` and `"activeTab"` in my permissions, as well as the page that the extension is for.

Can anyone point me in the right direction from here? Glad to provide more information if needed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. You **can** use the background page/script with Manifest v2. The [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifestVersion) says:

> The background_page property has been replaced with a `background` property that contains either a `scripts` or `page` property. Details are available in the [Event Pages](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages) documentation.
> 2. You **can** use `chrome.tabs.insertCSS` from a popup/background script
> 3. You **can't** use `chrome.tabs.insertCSS` from a content script

So if you want to inject the CSS file inside your content script you have two options:

1. [send a message](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) to the background script and insert the CSS file in the message listener
2. declare the CSS file in manifest.json under ["web_accessible_resources"](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/web_accessible_resources) key and simply add a `<link>` element that points to that CSS file:

   ```
    document.head.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend',
        '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="' + 
               chrome.runtime.getURL("starWars.css") + '">'
    );
   ```

Comment: This is awesome and really helpful! Thanks a ton. I'll give it a try and let you know how it goes.

Comment: The 2nd option worked wonderfully for my purposes. Thank you so much, you've been more than helpful. I would upvote if I could (don't have enough credit), thank you!